# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\limits{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{n}+1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

> Compute the following limit: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\limits{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{n}+1}$$.

So I thought to use the result:

> **a)** If $\{F_n\}$ converges uniformly on $S=[a,b]$ to $F$ and $F_n$ is integrable $\forall n$. Then $\int_\limits{a}^{b}F(x)dx=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_\limits{a}^{b}F_n(x)dx$.

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\limits{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{n}+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\limits{0}^{1-\delta}\frac{dx}{x^{n}+1}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\limits{1-\delta}^{1+\delta}\frac{dx}{x^{n}+1}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\limits{1+\delta}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{n}+1}
$$

I can easily pass the limit under the integral in the first and third integral which gives me the results  of $1-\delta$ and $0$ respectively.

However my problems lie in the second integral: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_\limits{1-\delta}^{1+\delta}\frac{dx}{x^n+1}$

I changed the variable $y=1-x$ which led me to $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_\limits{-\delta}^{\delta}\frac{dy}{(1-y)^{n}+1}=?$

**Question**:

How do I compute  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_\limits{-\delta}^{\delta}\frac{dy}{(1-y)^{n}+1}=$? As the delta is arbitrary I do not know how $1-y$ is going to behave.

Comment: Your last integral is bounded by $2\delta$, which is really all you need.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I guess that is right, as $\delta\to 0$ the result would be one for the original expression.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I have been thinking about what you said. Is it true that the limit can go under the integral? $Y$ can be negative

Comment: A super-overkill method is to [evaluate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-fracxn1-xmdx) the integral to $\frac{\pi/n}{\sin(\pi/n)}$ and then taking $n\to\infty$. Don't have to say this is not the recommended method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$\left|\int_\limits{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{n}+1}-1 \right|\leq \left| \int_\limits{0}^{1-\delta}\frac{dx}{x^{n}+1} -(1-\delta)\right|+ \left| \int_\limits{1-\delta}^{1+\delta}\frac{dx}{x^{n}+1}-2 \delta \right|+\left| \int_\limits{1+\delta}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{n}+1}\right|+3 \delta$$

and 
$$0 \leq \int_\limits{1-\delta}^{1+\delta}\frac{dx}{x^{n}+1} \leq \int_\limits{1-\delta}^{1+\delta}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^n+1}=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{0+1}$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^n+1}=\int_1^\infty0\,dx.$$
In both cases one can appeal to the Monotone Convergence theorem.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not supposed to use the Monotone Convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with the limit in the middle integral, treat it like $n$ is large, then approximate the integral (bound the integrand from above by $1$). You should end up with a direct $\delta$ dependence. If you let $\delta $ be arbitrary, what does that tell you the middle integral must be?